# In Rails how do I use find_each method with index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I can use Rails find_each method like :

```
User.find_each(:batch_size => 10000) do |user|
  ------
end
```

With find_each method is there any way to get the index of the array ? like :

```
User.find_each(:batch_size => 10000).with_index do |user, index|
  ------
end
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Update:** As of Rails 4.1.4 this is possible. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25241376/26604) for more. Example:

```
User.find_each(:batch_size => 1000).with_index do |user, index|
  user.call_method(index)
end
```

---

As you can see from the [method definition](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.2/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb#L24-L28), this is not possible.

```
def find_each(options = {})
  find_in_batches(options) do |records|
    records.each { |record| yield record }
  end
end
```

In order to accomplish what you want to do, you need to either create your own modified version of the method

```
class User
  def find_each(options = {})
    find_in_batches(options) do |records|
      records.each_with_index { |record| yield record, index }
    end
  end
end

User.find_each(:batch_size => 10000) do |user, index|
  ------
end
```

or use an instance variable.

```
index = 0
User.find_each(:batch_size => 10000) do |user|
  # ...
  index += 1
end
```

There is no other default solution as shown by the method implementation.

Comment: yes I got it..
A small modification in the user model code:

    `def self.find_each(options = {})
        find_in_batches(options) do |records|
         records.each_with_index { |record, index| yield record, index }
        end
  end`
Now its working.. Thanks...

Comment: I have written find_each_with_index method. But this find_each_with_index method is 
`repeating the index after each batch sizes!! No use of the index now.`
 So I used a variable to get the indexes with find_each method.

Comment: Take a look to Ron answer if you're using rails 4

Comment: @Naremy when I asked this qn, this functionality was not implemented in  any Rails versions.  Now it has. thx

Answer (score 78):

As an update to this question. Active Record **4.1.4** has added support for `find_each.with_index` as pointed in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html).

```
User.find_each(:batch_size => 1000).with_index do |user, index|
  user.call_method(index)
end
```

Comment: Note: `batch_size` defaults to `1000` so if that suits your needs you can just use `User.find_each.with_index`. https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each

Answer (score 12):

Your question is already implemented in the Rails master branch. To get this, it requires using Rails edge, as this has not been merged into any release as of yet. See this merged pull request: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/10992.

So add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
```

This will allow you to run the code you described:

```
User.find_each(batch_size: 10000).with_index do |user, index|
  puts "UserID: #{user.id.to_s} has index ##{index.to_s}"
end
```

Granted, running on the edge release is risky, so don't do this in production. But look at the pull request to see the small amount of code added to get this working. You can monkey patch until it is merged into a Rails release.

Comment: Thanks...Martin.. This is the another solution for my Qn. And glad that Rails is including this method! Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Just use an local variable:

```
index = 0
User.find_each(:batch_size => 10000) do |user|
  ------
  index += 1
end
```

Answer (score -6):

You can get all users and send them through a block along with their corresponding index as follows.

```
User.all.each_with_index do |user, index|
  puts "email is " + "#{user.email}" + " and user index is " + "#{index}"
end
```

Comment: The Main reason I am using the find_each instead of the .all is to reduce the mysql load. Because I have a huge user data.